# Can Asynchronously Update Datebase and Webgrid Only Once Without Full Refresh of Page MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following HTML being rendered in an MVC4 application's webgrid.

```
<tr class="webgrid-row-style">
   <td class="webgrid-column-style">
<span class="activate"><label id="lblMTPrinterID1">MT1</label></span>
<span class="deactivate"><label id="lblMTPrinterID2">MT1</label></span>
  </td>
  <td class="webgrid-column-style">
<span class="activate"><label id="lblNTPrinterID1">NT1</label></span>
<span class="deactivate"><label id="lblNTPrinterID2">NT1</label></span>
  </td>
  <td class="webgrid-active-column-style">
<span class="activate selector"><label id="lblActive1">N</label></span>
<span class="deactivate selector"><label id="lblActive2">N</label></span>
  </td>
  <td class="webgrid-column-style">
<button class="activate edit-user">Activate</button>
<button class="deactivate edit-user">Deactivate</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
  <td class="webgrid-column-style">
<span class="activate"><label id="lblMTPrinterID1">MT2</label></span>
<span class="deactivate"><label id="lblMTPrinterID2">MT2</label></span>
  </td>
  <td class="webgrid-column-style">
<span class="activate"><label id="lblNTPrinterID1">NT2</label></span>
<span class="deactivate"><label id="lblNTPrinterID2">NT2</label></span>
   </td>
   <td class="webgrid-active-column-style">
<span class="activate selector"><label id="lblActive1">Y</label></span>
<span class="deactivate selector"><label id="lblActive2">Y</label></span>
   </td>
   <td class="webgrid-column-style">
<button class="activate edit-user">Activate</button>
<button class="deactivate edit-user">Deactivate</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I am using the following jQuery code to activate or deactivate row elements successfully. I am then using AJAX to update underlying database table and refresh the webgrid.

```
$(function () {
$('tr.webgrid-row-style, tr.webgrid-alternating-row').each(function () {
    var Active = $(this).find("#lblActive1").text();
    var MTPrinterID = $(this).find("#lblMTPrinterID1").text();
    var NTPrinterID = $(this).find("#lblNTPrinterID1").text();
    if (Active == "Y") {
        $(this).find('.activate').hide();
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('.deactivate').hide();
    }

    $(this).find('.edit-user').on('click', function updateWebGrid() {
            var printermapping =
            {
                "MTPrinterID": MTPrinterID,
                "NTPrinterID": NTPrinterID,
                "Active": "N"
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/UpdatePrinterMapping/',
                data: JSON.stringify(printermapping),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#gridContent").load('/Home/ #gridContent', function () {
                        $('tr.webgrid-row-style, tr.webgrid-alternating-row').each(function () {
                            var Active = $(this).find("#lblActive1").text();
                            if (Active == "Y") {
                                $(this).find('.activate').hide();
                            }
                            else {
                                $(this).find('.deactivate').hide();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        }
.
.
```

The trouble is I can do this only once using this approach. After the webgrid is refreshed once by using the .load function, nothing is chained to the click function of the buttons represented by the edit-user class. So I cannot update the database and webgrid again without first refreshing the whole page (which defeats the purpose). I think I have to do some sort of recursive call for function updateWebGrid(). I have tried a few things but with no success so far. Can someone please help? And thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you bind an event handler to `.edit-user` button, but after `load` method completes and `#gridContent`'s html is repopulated, there's already a **new** button, and it doesn't have any registered event handlers.

The solution is to bind the handler to a top-level element, which will not be deleted or recreated. For example:

```
<script>
    function showHideButtons(grid) {
        grid.find('tr.webgrid-row-style, tr.webgrid-alternating-row').each(function() {
            var th = $(this);
            var Active = th.find("#lblActive1").text();
            if(Active == "Y") {
                th.find('.activate').hide();
            } else {
                th.find('.deactivate').hide();
            }
        });
    }

    $(function() {
        var gridContent = $('#grid-content');
        showHideButtons(gridContent);    

        gridContent.on('click', '.edit-user', function() {
            var tableRow = $(this).closest('tr'); //find table row, that contains clicked button
            var printerMapping = {
                Active: tableRow.find("#lblActive1").text(),
                MTPrinterID: tableRow.find("#lblMTPrinterID1").text(),
                NTPrinterID: tableRow.find("#lblNTPrinterID1").text()
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/UpdatePrinterMapping/',
                data: JSON.stringify(printermapping),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(response) {
                    gridContent.load('/Home/#gridContent', function() {
                        showHideButtons(gridContent);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I am going through it now and will let you know if success :)